# Tension in polymer using Ising model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I am solving a problem on statistical mechanics. The question is:
[image]

Since it is based on the Ising model and also given in the question that the monomers can take two values, either compact or elongated. Using the given data, I arrived at the following results: $$N_c+N_e = N$$
$$N_cl_c+N_el_e = L$$
where $N_c$ is the number of compact monomers, and $N_e$ is the number of elongated monomers. Using this, I can obtain $N_c$ and $N_e$, but I don't know how to proceed with the first question.

Any help or any link to any reference would be beneficial.
Not a homework question. Just need reference material where I can read about the concept related to the first question. I don't even know how to proceed with the first question.